# How to verify that the application has just started?

Tags: java, android

How to verify that the application has just started?
This is the correct way?

```
if(getIntent().getAction() != null && getIntent().getAction().equals("android.intent.action.MAIN")) {
```

Comment: I don't see a problem here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I find my method described above doesn't work correctly.

```
MyApp app = (MyApp)getApplication();
if(app.isJustStarted) {
```

and

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
public boolean isJustStarted = true; }
```

is solution for problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can always know it at [`onCreate()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate%28android.os.Bundle%29). In case the user changes device's orientation, normally your activity will be closed by the system and will be re-created. If you don't want that, consider adding `android:configChanges` to your activity (in `AndroidManifest.xml`) as follows:

```
<activity
    android:name="..."
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
    android:label="..." >
```